# Play console reports crashes that occur during development

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, google-play, google-play-console

I am seeing a lot of crashes and performance related issues in Google play console, Most of them are once that i faced during development.

I am also using crashlytics, and it has option to disable crashlytics during debugging, but i am unable to find out any option like this for `Play Console Crash Reporting tool`

Comment: Apart from your problem, are you debugging your production version from the play store?

Comment: @Ch4t4r : I have changed the version code from gradle. In Production, version code is set to 1.9.7 and in development version code is set to 1.9.8

Comment: Then you shouldn't receive crashes in your play console for that version. The crashes are only sent when the device has the play services installed and the app was installed over the play store. That you still receive the crashes vor that version (which I guess you checked is true?) indicates that you are using the same certificate for debugging and release. Is that true? If not, you might have found some sort of bug.

Comment: yes currently its set to `1.9.8`,  but i checked git history and it was updated a week after the production release. May be that's the issue, Can you please tell about the certificate thing? When i generate the `SignedAPK`, I choose the `.jks` file at that time.

Comment: All Android apps are signed. The debug build uses a default certificate for signing the .apk (in ~/.android/debug.keystore). For signing you use - as you stated - a keystore (`jks` = java KeyStore) different from the debug one. If you'd configured your app to always use the same keystore for release and debug I'd have understood your problem, but with all information you have provided so far there is no logical reason why you see the crashes in the console - after all, when installing the debug version over the release one HAS to be removed (because of the signing mismatch release <-> debug).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can disable crashlytics it in debug mode.

Put it in your class which extends Application class in `onCreate` method

```
// Set up Crashlytics, disabled for debug builds
        Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
                .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
                .build();
        Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);
```

To disable in playstore we can achieve it by differentiate the applicationId` in debug and release modes:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.package"
        ...
    }
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }
        debug {
            ...
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
    }
...
}
```

**Note:** This solution works when you are not using any libs, but it can break things up when using library that are configured with applicationId for example you use this approach if you are using billing app library may you no longer able to test in app billing in your app.

Comment: Thanks, but this will disable crashlytics, I need to disable Google Play Console crash reporting tool.

Comment: This required much more changes. I think, i also need to change the `play-services.json` file.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.myapp.app1'